# How to fix stopwatch from incrementing when "start" is pressed?

Tags: javascript, time

I've created a simple stopwatch. It has 3 buttons, "Start", "Stop", and "Reset". They work, but there are some flaws. Once I hit "Start" it continues to increment and speeds the clock up, which causes you to have to hit "Stop" multiple times to stop the clock.

I believe it's a problem in the add function or the onclick event, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

The add() function:

```
function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + 
    (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();    
}
```

onclick for start button:

```
// Start
start.onclick = timer;
```

The desired result is that once you hit start, it should start the clock and regardless of how many times you hit, it should not continue to increment and once you hit stop, it should stop the clock.

EDIT 1: 
Code for `setInterval()`:

```
function timer() {
    t = setInterval(add, 1000);
}
```

EDIT 2: 
Code for "stop" and "reset" functions:

```
// Stop 
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(t);
}

// Reset
reset.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(t);
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

Comment: are you using `setInterval()`? Each click would be adding an interval so multiple callbacks are firing instead of just the one. If it's already running, `start` should either do nothing or set it back to 0 or something

Comment: @Anthony No, I'm using ```setTimeout()```. I tried using ```setInterval()``` but that only increased the time exponentially.

Comment: you will experience a similar problem with `setTimeout()`. Can you update the question to show where you are calling `setTimeout()`?

Comment: What's `timer`?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, just updated it.

Comment: I always shiver when I see a clock, incrementally counting seconds. Take a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/48746638/6567275

Comment: @Thomas Haha yeah it seems to be causing me some issues. I'm really new to javascript so this the best I could do to actually make a working clock. I'm more familiar with python.

Comment: clearInterval will be needed to stop the interval;

Comment: https://quentinuk.github.io/stopWatch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm really new to javascript so this the best I could do to actually make a working clock. I'm more familiar with python.

OK, then let's take it simple and slow

### The Stopwatch:

A better approach than counting the seconds, minutes and hours on an interval, and therefore introducing an error with every increment *(the intervals in JS are not accurate)* let's define the value on the stopwatch as the difference betwen `Date.now()` and somne `startTime`.

This is while the clock is running, we also need to store this `value` while the clock is not running. Before it has started, after it has stopped, ...

```js
var isRunning = false;
var value = 0;
var startTime = 0;

function getValue() {
  return isRunning ? Date.now() - startTime : value;
}
```

`getValue()` returns the number of milliseconds on the clock. That's all we need to calculate seconds, minutes, hours and days.

And we are independant of any update-interval. Every time we call the function it will give us an accurate value, wether that's every frame or once a hour.

Now let's add the code to start and stop the stopwatch

```js
function start() {
  if (isRunning) return;

  isRunning = true;
  // startTime = Date.now();
  // but we can do better, we can make this function to double as `restart`/`continue`
  startTime = Date.now() - value;
}

function stop() {
  if (!isRunning) return;

  isRunning = false;
  value = Date.now() - startTime;
}

// just resets the (computed) value to 0.
// does not `stop()` the stopwatch if it is running.
function reset() {
  if (isRunning) {
    startTime = Date.now();
  } else {
    value = 0;
  }
}
```

Since `start()` and `stop()` check wether the stopwatch `isRunning` or not, there's no issue if you call them multiple times.

### Rendering / UI:

```js
// leading zero
function lz(value) {
  return (value < 10 ? "0" : "") + value;
}

function render() {
  var val = getValue(), v = Math.abs(val);

  var sign = val < 0 ? "-": "";
  var seconds = Math.floor(v/1000)%60,
      minutes = Math.floor(v/60000)%60,
      hours = Math.floor(v/3600000)%24;

  h1.textContent = sign + lz(hours) + ":" + lz(minutes) + ":" + lz(seconds);
}
```

The simplest would be to just render the value all the time

```js
setInterval(render, 1000);
```

downside is that it renders the same value over and over while the stopwatch is not running. but imo. a neglectable overhead *(at least for one stopwatch at an 1000ms inteval)*

or you have to add/remove the interval on start and stop:

```js
var interval;

function start() {
  // ...
  interval = setInterval(render, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  // ...
  clearInterval(interval);
  render();
}

function reset() {
  // ...
  render();
}
```

---

### Summary:

```js
var isRunning = false;
var value = 0;
var startTime = 0;
var interval;

function getValue() {
  return isRunning ? Date.now() - startTime : value;
}

function start() {
  if (isRunning) return;

  isRunning = true;
  startTime = Date.now() - value;
  interval = setInterval(render, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  if (!isRunning) return;

  isRunning = false;
  value = Date.now() - startTime;
  clearInterval(interval);
  render();
}

function reset() {
  if (isRunning) {
    startTime = Date.now();
  } else {
    value = 0;
  }
  render()
}

function lz(value) {
  return (value < 10 ? "0" : "") + value;
}

function render() {
  var val = getValue(),
    v = Math.abs(val);

  var sign = val < 0 ? "-" : "";
  var seconds = Math.floor(v / 1000) % 60,
    minutes = Math.floor(v / 60000) % 60,
    hours = Math.floor(v / 3600000) % 24;

  h1.textContent = sign + lz(hours) + ":" + lz(minutes) + ":" + lz(seconds);
}

var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
// I know, it's cheap/dirty to select the buttons by their label
document.querySelector("input[value=start]").onclick = start;
document.querySelector("input[value=stop]").onclick = stop;
document.querySelector("input[value=reset]").onclick = reset;
render();
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<input type="button" value="start" />
<input type="button" value="stop" />
<input type="button" value="reset" />
```

or with `requestAnimationFrame()`:

```js
var isRunning = false;
var value = 0;
var startTime = 0;

function getValue() {
  return isRunning ? Date.now() - startTime : value;
}

function start() {
  if (isRunning) return;

  isRunning = true;
  startTime = Date.now() - value;
  render();
}

function stop() {
  if (!isRunning) return;

  isRunning = false;
  value = Date.now() - startTime;
  render();
}

function reset() {
  if (isRunning) {
    startTime = Date.now();
  } else {
    value = 0;
    render();
  }
}

function lz(value) {
  return (value < 10 ? "0" : "") + value;
}

function render() {
  if (isRunning) requestAnimationFrame(render);
  var val = getValue(),
    v = Math.abs(val);

  var sign = val < 0 ? "-" : "";
  var ms = v % 1000,
    seconds = Math.floor(v / 1000) % 60,
    minutes = Math.floor(v / 60000) % 60,
    hours = Math.floor(v / 3600000) % 24;

  h1.textContent = sign + lz(hours) + ":" + lz(minutes) + ":" + lz(seconds) + "." + ms.toString().padStart(3, 0);
}

var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
// I know, it's cheap/dirty to select the buttons by their label
document.querySelector("input[value=start]").onclick = start;
document.querySelector("input[value=stop]").onclick = stop;
document.querySelector("input[value=reset]").onclick = reset;
render();
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<input type="button" value="start" />
<input type="button" value="stop" />
<input type="button" value="reset" />
```

and since we never use `value` and `startTime` at the same time; actually they are quite the two sides of computing the same value, we can combine them into one variable `offset`; you may like this "cleanup" or not, that's why I only add this at the very end.

```js
var isRunning = false;
var offset = 0;

function getValue() {
  return isRunning ? Date.now() + offset : offset;
}

function start() {
  if (isRunning) return;

  isRunning = true;
  offset -= Date.now();
  render();
}

function stop() {
  if (!isRunning) return;

  isRunning = false;
  offset += Date.now();
  render();
}

function reset() {
  if (isRunning) {
    offset = -Date.now();
  } else {
    offset = 0;
    render();
  }
}

function lz(value) {
  return (value < 10 ? "0" : "") + value;
}

function render() {
  if (isRunning) requestAnimationFrame(render);
  var val = getValue(),
    v = Math.abs(val);

  var sign = val < 0 ? "-" : "";
  var ms = v % 1000,
    seconds = Math.floor(v / 1000) % 60,
    minutes = Math.floor(v / 60000) % 60,
    hours = Math.floor(v / 3600000) % 24;

  h1.textContent = sign + lz(hours) + ":" + lz(minutes) + ":" + lz(seconds) + "." + ms.toString().padStart(3, 0);
}

var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
document.querySelector("input[value=start]").onclick = start;
document.querySelector("input[value=stop]").onclick = stop;
document.querySelector("input[value=reset]").onclick = reset;
render();
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<input type="button" value="start" />
<input type="button" value="stop" />
<input type="button" value="reset" />
```

### Edit:

> This works great. I added clearInterval(interval); under startTime = Date.now() under the if statement for function reset() so when reset is pressed it stops the clock. However, I can't restart the clock after doing so. Is there a way to have reset() stop the clock, reset it, then be able to start the timer over?

You forgot to update `isRunning`. that way, you just stopped rendering the value, while she stopwatch is actually still running.

If that's the behaviour you want you should use

```js
function reset() {
  stop();     // stop the watch, with everything what's necessary for that
  value = 0;  // reset the value
  render();   // render this changed value (once)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great. I added ```clearInterval(interval);``` under ```startTime = Date.now()``` under the if statement for ```function reset()``` so when reset is pressed it stops the clock. However, I can't restart the clock after doing so. Is there a way to have ```reset()``` stop the clock, reset it, then be able to start the timer over?

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could change `timer()` as follows:

```
function timer() {
  if(!t) {
    t = setInterval(add, 1000)
  } else {
    clearInterval(t);
    t = null;
  }
}
```

This way you will only end up with a single `setInterval()` called.

Comment: When doing this, it causes the timer to only add a value of 1 second to the timer, and then the timer can't increment and has to be reset. Is there a way to have it continue incrementing?

Comment: Oops yep, you will want to use `setInterval`, I will update

Comment: Isn't ```clearInterval()``` or ```t = 0;``` what's causing the problem though? Because ```else```  is enacted once ```t``` no longer equals 0 so then it clears the interval not allowing it to continue incrementing?  I tried ```else { setInterval(0);}``` so that it once ```t``` is no longer equal to 0 it would add "nothing" to the clock, which works, but once "reset" is pressed it causes the clock to break.

Comment: `t` is a handle to the interval; by calling `setInterval` or `setTimeout` multiple times, you are creating multiple callbacks invoked every 1000 ms (in this case).  Before this change, `t` would just get overridden each time to be the handle to the latest `setInterval`

Comment: Right, but once ```t > 1``` and you stop the clock, "start" can no longer be invoked. How would you get the clock to continue after having clicked "stop" or "start"?  I'll edit the question again to let you see the stop and reset functions; perhaps that might be a little more helpful.

Comment: ```Stop``` does ```clearInterval(t)``` right? Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: Updated - I didn't realize it would need to be explicitly defined as `null`/`undefined` so it will fail the `if()` check

Comment: That what needs to be defined as ```null```? The ```t``` under the ```else``` statement?

Comment: Yeah, so next time you click start (after stop/reset), it will be falsey `if(!t)` and it will start a new interval